# Hide primary key from form in ofbiz

Tags: ofbiz

Can anyone help me please? I want to add a new training dataset to the database, the problem is that in the form I use auto-field-service and it gets me the primary key. I want to hide the primary key from the view. My service name is tariningService.

This is my service:

```
<service name="tariningService"  default-entity-name="TrainingClassType" engine="java" location="org.apache.ofbiz.humanres.TwHumanResService" invoke="createFormation" auth="true">
      <auto-attributes include="pk" mode="INOUT" optional="true"/>
      <auto-attributes include="nonpk" mode="IN" optional="true"/>
      <override name="description" optional="true"/>
    </service>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this would help? http://markmail.org/message/6jgdb7scckfl3xok " element supported in form widget  element?"

Comment: Also this does not related with mysql, so I'd remove the related label